# Is "et al" always accompanied by a period?

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations, periods

In this sentence, is it necessary to include a period with et al?

This is an interesting paper, written by G. Andrews et al. Here, et al means Dr. X, Dr. Y, and Dr.Z.

Does the second et al need a period? Like et al.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it should always be accompanied by a period.

Since *et al.* is the abbreviation of *and others*, where *et al.* could be an abbreviation for [*et alii*, *et aliae* or *et alia*](http://editingandwritingservices.com/how-do-i-punctuate-et-al/) when referring to masculine, feminine or gender neutral groups respectively.