# et al. with an apostrophe

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe

There are [other et al. questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389956/is-et-al-always-accompanied-by-a-period) so I'll cut to the chase. Is it correct to have et al. with an apostrophe to indicate ownership?

> Bloggs et al.'s paper was good. I am going to interpret Bloggs et
>   al.'s work. Bloggs et al.'s analysis of Morsov et al.'s study was
>   mediocre.

Comment: Hmm, I don’t think I’ve ever seen it written that way in academia. I suppose since *Jack and Jill’s paper* is fine, so *Jack et al’s paper* should be as well. It just sounds odd to me.

Comment: @Lawrence yes, it really does, hence the question. However, if it's *technically* the right way to right it, I'm happy enough.

Comment: I’ve upvoted your question. Let’s see what answers come in.

Comment: Hello, Stumbler. 'Technically' isn't well-defined hereabouts, and it's usually best avoided like the plague when followed by 'correct' etc when discussing grammar, punctuation and the like. (By the way, this is a question about punctuation style, not grammar the way it is strictly defined on ELU. I've altered the tag.) // Cutting to the chase, ELU also expects every man to do his research and to show what they've done (even if it's as unappetising as 'Yale Style Guide for Science Writing doesn't mention it, and neither do X and Z.') I **can** give a sensible suggestion: as Lawrence ...

Comment: says, it makes sense as it mirrors _Jack and Jill's incident_. However, I drop the period from all abbreviations, and many don't agree with that (I've found various authorities who do accept the style though). The usage is jarring (a) because it's unusual in itself and (b) because it groups punctuation marks unusually. We usually advise people with this sort of grey-area problem to check in the in-house style guide, and on finding it's not covered, to ask a tutor, institution authority on scientific writing style, etc. The 'rules' may be different at the institution just down the road.

Comment: Peter Shor gives the traditional (and probably accepted in the vast majority of formal circles) answer at the duplicate (even though he uses a 'grammar' tag). However, I'd weight his comment about the advisability of rephrasing as being the more important part of his answer.

Comment: @We oath to creation It's certainly addressed there, though the question is poorly phrased. Have you close-voted here?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I flagged for the duplicate (mainly because of the answer there). Not sure if that also does 'close-vote'.